# rake db:test:prepare erroring out due to PG error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

Some of my rSpec tests are failing and I suspect it's due to the test database not being cleared out.  When I try to run rake db:test:prepare, I'm getting the error below (i'm in Rails 3.2).  Clearly, this looks like some kind of Postgres issue, looks like the rake task is trying to drop the test database so it can repopulate it.  Production database schema loads fine.

I've looked for the rake task in lib/tasks/ but I haven't been able to find it.  Anyone have any idea on what's going on?

```
osx_user-> rake db:test:prepare
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ""
                                ^
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ""
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `async_exec'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `block in execute'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:649:in `execute'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:772:in `drop_database'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:623:in `drop_database'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:532:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:559:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/osx_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  My database.yml file for the development environment was set like this:

```
database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME_TEST'] %>
```

The rake task was looking for an environmental variable that did not exist.